# Dummy account in Google Developer Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After we created a new project in Google developer console, we see one App Engine service account and one Google APIs service account already there in "Permission" page. But we have no client Ids in credential. Those two accounts seems to be dummy,  what are they for?

Answer (score 1):

They are not exactly dummy.

Those are "service" accounts meant to be used if you want an application or utility/tool that is sitting **inside/on** your app engine VM or compute engine VM, to perform actions that will require authentication ... having service accounts should ideally let you can skip the oauth step which would otherwise require browser access and user intervention ... things that an automated process in a VM should not have to deal with.

I'm guessing they were provisioned automatically with ease of use (? shrug) in mind so folks wouldn't have to go about creating them.

1. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#serviceaccounts
2. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication

Comment: thanks for reply. I know what service accounts are. Those two accounts 'provisioned' automatically are not actually available for use. For example, with a service account, you should use it with a key file, either in JSON or P12 format, but since we cannot see it in the credential setting, you cannot get keys and thus cannot really use it in your application.